# Issues after updating Composer 2

Tags: composer

I have been using drupal for over a month now. I am unable to install modules properly because of the composer 2 updating issues.

So far I have made the following changes while updating composer 2
"oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2",
"wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2",
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8"

When I try composer update I get the following errors

```
Problem 1
    - acquia/lightning 4.1.11 requires drupal/lightning_media ^3.14 || ^4.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/lightning_media[3.14.0, ..., 3.x-dev (alias of dev-3.x), 4.1.0, ..., 4.x-dev (alias of dev-4.x)].
    - acquia/lightning[4.1.12, ..., 4.1.15] require drupal/lightning_media ^3.21 || ^4.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/lightning_media[3.21.0, 3.x-dev (alias of dev-3.x), 4.6.0, 4.x-dev (alias of dev-4.x)].
    - drupal/lightning_media 4.x-dev is an alias of drupal/lightning_media dev-4.x and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - drupal/lightning_media[dev-4.x, 3.15.0, 4.3.0, ..., 4.6.0] require drupal/slick_entityreference ^2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/slick_entityreference[2.0.0-rc1, 2.0.0, 2.x-dev (alias of dev-2.x)].
    - drupal/slick_entityreference 2.x-dev is an alias of drupal/slick_entityreference dev-2.x and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - drupal/lightning_media 3.x-dev is an alias of drupal/lightning_media dev-3.x and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - drupal/lightning_media[3.14.0, 4.1.0, ..., 4.2.0] require oomphinc/composer-installers-extender ^1.1 -> found oomphinc/composer-installers-extender[v1.1, v1.1.1, v1.1.2] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0).
    - drupal/lightning_media 3.16.0 requires drupal/slick 2.0 -> found drupal/slick[2.0.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.0.0).
    - drupal/lightning_media[dev-3.x, 3.17.0, ..., 3.21.0] require drupal/slick ^2.0 -> found drupal/slick[dev-2.x, 2.0.0-alpha1, ..., 2.x-dev (alias of dev-2.x)] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.0.0).
    - drupal/slick_entityreference[dev-2.x, 2.0.0-rc1, ..., 2.0.0] require drupal/slick ~2.0 -> found drupal/slick[dev-2.x, 2.0.0-alpha1, ..., 2.x-dev (alias of dev-2.x)] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.0.0).
    - Root composer.json requires acquia/lightning ~4.1.11 -> satisfiable by acquia/lightning[4.1.11, ..., 4.1.15].
```

And when I try to add composer require acquia/lightning

```
 Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires oomphinc/composer-installers-extender ^2.0, found oomphinc/composer-installers-extender[2.0.0] but the package is fixed to v1.1.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - grasmash/drupal-security-warning is locked to version 1.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - grasmash/drupal-security-warning 1.1.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 3
    - acquia/lightning 5.2.x-dev requires drupal/lightning_media ^4.6 -> found drupal/lightning_media[dev-4.x, 4.6.0, 4.x-dev (alias of dev-4.x)] but the package is fixed to 3.14.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - acquia/lightning 5.2.0 requires drupal/core ^9.2 -> found drupal/core[9.2.0-alpha1, ..., 9.3.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^8.8.10).
    - Root composer.json requires acquia/lightning ^5.2 -> satisfiable by acquia/lightning[5.2.0, 5.2.x-dev].
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Upgrading to Composer 2 might take a little time, but since Lightning is EOL this year (https://www.acquia.com/blog/acquia-lightning-eol-2021-acquia-cms-future), I would stick with Composer 1 for now and make the switch to Composer 2 when you move away from Lightning.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Thanks how can I revert back to the previous version of the composer. I am using drupal for a about a month now.  I understand that if I type the version of the composer it will . But I am unsure what version it was

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597051/how-to-downgrade-or-install-a-specific-version-of-composer